# How to remove fonts and styles of text in php

Tags: php

I wanted to know how to convert text with font and style to plain text without font with php and also remove emoji?
Example : 
To : Simple

Comment: How does a string have a font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `Normalizer`.

```
Normalizer::normalize($yourString);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php

Comment: I used FORM_KC. That's right, thank you